# How to receive multiple JSON object and an Uri Parameter in WebAPI Controller

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

I came over the following scenario when trying out ASP.NET Web API2. I have a WebAPI2 Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/service/receiver/{date}")]
public IHttpActionResult receiver([FromUri]  string date, [FromBody List<car> cars)

}
```

Now I can call this with the following jQuery:

```
<script>
    var carsData = [{ "model": "Audi" }, { "model": "BMW" }, { "model": "Audi" }];

    var uri = 'api/service/receiver/20180107';

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: uri,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify(carsData),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        },
        failure: function (errMsg) {
            alert(errMsg);
        }
    });
</script>
```

This works fine, but I have no clue how to post multiple complex Objects or maybe a complex JSON object and multiple additional parameters.

I tried:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/service/receiver/{date}")]
public IHttpActionResult receiver([FromUri]  string date, [FromBody List<car> cars, [FromBody] List<company> companies)

}
```

and also

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/service/receiver/{date}")]
public IHttpActionResult receiver([FromUri]  string date, [FromBody List<car> cars, string company)

}
```

and then in the jQuery Call I changed the `data` line

```
data: JSON.stringify({ cars: carsData, companies: compData }),
```

and also to

```
data: JSON.stringify({ cars: carsData, company: "theCompany" }),
```

But then i receive a 404 or null. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of, "FromBody" refers to **from the body of the HTTP request**. Basically, the body of the received request is taken and converted into an object (by default by deserializing JSON). MVC.NET will take the entire body and make an object. This is the reason you can't have two `[FromBody]`.

Based on your jQuery, what you are trying to do is pass `{ cars: carsData, companies: compData }` and `{ cars: carsData, company: "theCompany" }` both of which entire objects sent as the body. Each of these objects have two properties (`cars` and `companies`) and (`cars` and `company`) respectively. Since you are passing these as whole objects to the body, MVC will need to deserialize the body into an entire string as well.

You will have to make a new class:

```
class MyCarData {
    public List<car> cars { get; set; }
    public List<company> companies { get; set; }
}
```

You can then use `[FromBody] MyCarData` in your controller to access it as a whole.

Comment: Neville, along with using “MyCarData” ViewModel, the OP will also need to send JSON data as a single object containing arrays of “carsData” and “compData”. Even when each array has only one item in it.

Comment: yes, that is exactly what `MyCarData` accepts. if the array has only one value the list would only have one value.

Comment: Right, that’s indirect way of saying it. It’s just that, I believe the answer should cover all aspects directly. :)

Comment: what are the aspects? in the jquery OP provided, `carsData` is an array. besides this OP is just trying variations to see what allows him to send multiple objects. if he really wants all those variations to work it would make most sense by several principles to have a seperate action for each

Comment: That’s the point, he has tried different variations He should also be guided to right version of variation.

Comment: he tries variations to get anything working. Which variation he really needs to use is up to him based on what he is trying to do. The above code shows how to do it in the server. This above code is quite straightforward and the variations are implied. If the OP still has questions on each variation, let him ask.